# Setting conditions for classList.toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that's triggered by `onClick`. Here's the [example](https://codepen.io/loudenwilhelm/pen/PEmWZr). I want to only be able to trigger the function 'slide1' when 'slide2' is not triggered. I tried setting up a conditional statement like this:

```
function slide1() {
    btn1.classList.toggle('slide', btn2.className != 'slide');
}
```

I also tried an `if` statement like this:

```
function slide1() {
    if(btn2.className != 'slide') {
    btn1.classList.toggle('slide');
    }
}
```

That didn't work either.

I just need a simple way to toggle classes if certain conditions are met; without jQuery or a library. Thanks.

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

function slide1() {
  btn1.classList.toggle('slide');
}

function slide2() {
  btn2.classList.toggle('slide');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  transition: 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#btn1 {
  background: blue;
}

#btn2 {
  background: red;
  left: 50%;
}

#btn1.slide {
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 999;
}

#btn2.slide {
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn1" onClick="slide1();">
  left
</div>
<div id="btn2" onClick="slide2();">
  right
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** [Here](https://codepen.io/loudenwilhelm/pen/PEmWZr?editors=0010) is an expanded example of the problem I'm dealing with. There are several elements with classes that need to be toggled only under certain circumstances. If 'panel1' is triggered when 'panel2' has already been triggered, then 'panel1' will cover 'panel2'. and the same with 'panel3'.

Comment: the `if` statement works for me.

Comment: Does the button have any other classes? If it does, you should use `btn2.classList.contains("slide")` as in the answer below.

Comment: @Barmar in my actual code, i have many additional elements with different classes

Comment: Since `.className` contains *all* the classes, you can't use `==` or `!=` to test for a specific class.

Comment: You should make the code you posted reflect the reality of the situation. You simplified it too much, so it doesn't have the problem any more. Also, you don't have the `if` statement that you're asking about in the code.

Comment: @Barmar heres the updated code with my actual problem https://codepen.io/loudenwilhelm/pen/PEmWZr?editors=0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, the proper way to check if an element has a class in JavaScript is [element.classList.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

So, in your example, you should replace the condition with

```
if(btn2.className.contains('slide')) {
  ...
}
```

---

As a sidenote, having different functions doing the exact same thing on different elements should be avoided, where possible. Instead of having two functions, you should have only one and use the click event's target:

```js
let halves = document.querySelectorAll("div");

function slide(event) {
  // remove `slide` class from both divs:
  [].map.call(halves, function(half){
    half.classList.remove('slide');
  });
  // add `slide` class to currently clicked div:
  event.target.classList.add('slide')
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  transition: 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#btn1 {
  background: blue;
}

#btn2 {
  background: red;
  left: 50%;
}

#btn1.slide {
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 999;
}

#btn2.slide {
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn1" onClick="slide(event);">
  left
</div>
<div id="btn2" onClick="slide(event);">
  right
</div>
```

On a different note, I assume you're aware the selectors used in both your question and my answer are outrageously generic and should never be used in production ready code.

---

And as a last note, your CSS is quite faulty but I'm not considering fixing it here, as it wouldn't help anyone except yourself, which goes against the first principle of SO: one answer should help multiple users having the same problem. Here's how I'd have coded your example:

```js
let br = document.querySelector('#blueRed');
br.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle('slide');
  [].map.call(br.querySelectorAll('div'), function(div) {
    if (div !== event.target) {
      div.classList.remove('slide');
    }
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#blueRed {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

#blueRed div {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: flex-grow 1s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#blueRed div:last-child {
  background-color: red;
}

#blueRed div.slide {
  flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="blueRed">
  <div>left</div>
  <div>right</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/dLwba40p/). Should be [prefixed](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

Comment: That's true, but since he's not adding any other classes his code should work.

Comment: So now we've learned from comments that he does have other classes. This is the correct answer.

Comment: `className.contains ` works great for testing when a class is present, but what about for testing if a class is not present?

Comment: also what faults were you referring to in my css?

Comment: `!className.contains('test')` will do. Your CSS is hugely generic. `* {transition: 1s ease }` can actually break complex websites on limited devices. But this is not the place to code review your CSS, really.

Comment: oh yeah i plan on polishing my css after i fix basic problems like this one, thanks for bringing it to my attention

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu could you give me an example of the `!className.contains('test')`

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/egd6omt7/ The negation (`!`) goes before the statement: `!element.classList.contains('yourClass')`. The by-the-book way of doing it would be `!(element.classList.contains('yourClass'))` but, as you can see, you can skip the parenthesis.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu i applied the `!` before my statement but that didnt seem to work either. would you mind looking at my source code and seeing whats happening https://codepen.io/loudenwilhelm/pen/PEmWZr my previous method for toggling classes is commented out in there too, (it kind of works but it's really buggy)

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: slide1 is not defined at HTMLDivElment.onclick (index.html:149)`. Basically complains about calling a function that has not yet been defined. Always keep your dev console open while developing (`F12` in most browsers). Also `btn2.className.contains is not a function at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (pen.js:12)`, because `className` is the string inside the `class` attribute of the element, not the `classList` object, which has the `.contains` property. It's `classList.contains`, not `className.contains`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your objective...

I condensed the functions into one and start off one button with the `className = 'slide'`. If one button is clicked then the class slide always alternates between the two buttons.

### Demo

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

function slide() {
  btn1.classList.toggle('slide');
  btn2.classList.toggle('slide');
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  transition: 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
}

div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#btn1 {
  background: blue;
}

#btn2 {
  background: red;
  left: 50%;
}

#btn1.slide {
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 999;
}

#btn2.slide {
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn1" onClick="slide();" class='slide'>
  left
</div>
<div id="btn2" onClick="slide();">
  right
</div>
```